# onItemClickListener is not working on a listView with coustom ArrayAdapter Class

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview, custom-arrayadapter

**NumbersActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<Word> words= new ArrayList<>();

        //words.add("zero");
        words.add(new Word("one","lutti",R.drawable.number_one));
        words.add(new Word("two","otiiko",R.drawable.number_two));
        words.add(new Word("three","tolookosu",R.drawable.number_three));
        words.add(new Word("four","oyyisa",R.drawable.number_four));
        words.add(new Word("five","massokka",R.drawable.number_five));
        words.add(new Word("six","temmokka",R.drawable.number_six));
        words.add(new Word("seven","kenekaku",R.drawable.number_seven));
        words.add(new Word("eight","kawinta",R.drawable.number_eight));
        words.add(new Word("nine","wo'e",R.drawable.number_nine));
        words.add(new Word("ten","na'aacha",R.drawable.number_ten));


        WordAdapter itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words,R.color.category_numbers);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, R.raw.number_one);
                mMediaPlayer.start();            }
            });


    }
}
```

**WordAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//To override getView method from array adapter click on
//Code>>Override Method >> getView
/**
 * {@link WordAdapter} is an {@link ArrayAdapter} that can provide the layout for each list item
 * based on a data source, which is a list of {@link Word} objects.
 */
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>{

    /**Resource ID for the background color for this list of words*/
    private int mColorResourceId;

    /**
     * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
     *
     * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
     * @param words is the list of {@link Word}s to be displayed.
     */
    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words,int colorResourceId){
        super(context,0,words);
        mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
        // Get the Miwok translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the Miwok TextView.
        miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the default TextView.
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
        ImageView imageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_icon);

        // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
        if(currentWord.hasImage()) {
            // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
            imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
            // Make sure the view is visible
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Set the theme color for the list item
        View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
        //Find the color that the resource ID maps to
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),mColorResourceId);
        //Set the background color of the text container View
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
        // the ListView.
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:background="@color/tan_background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_icon">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="lutti"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:text="one"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PLAY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

setOnClickListener method on ListView is not playing any media file neither it is displaying any toast message when trying to do so. It should play the same media mp3 file once a list Item is clicked . I am not able to identify the problem the code compiles successfully. A coustom array adapter was created called wordAdapter.

Comment: Please post the `list_item` layout.

Comment: I have updated the code for list_item

Comment: It's the `<Button>` that's causing the `OnItemClickListener` to not fire. Do you want the `Button` to respond to the clicks? Or the whole list item?

Comment: The whole list item

Comment: You could just remove the `<Button>` then. When list items only have one function, they usually don't have buttons anyway, since clicking the whole item is the common pattern. If you're using it as a label, though, you could simply change it to a `<TextView>` instead.

Comment: Oh, Thanks I was just trying to modify the layout and forgot to remove the button . Can you please explain why this happened

Comment: Basically, 'cause the `Button` was kind of intercepting clicks before they would be relayed up to the parent `<LinearLayout>`, which is what would fire the `OnItemClickListener`. Removing it, or changing it to something that's not focusable/clickable by default, lets the parent handle all of the touch events, so it can register clicks. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes got It thanx man!!